# My spring boot is of Microservice architecture. Getting 500 Internal Server between microservice calls using rest template

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

My spring boot is of Microservice architecture. Getting 500 Internal Server error logged in calling microservice.

Service A calls Service B with POST request. And Service B processed the request successfully and got 200 status code in Service B logs.
But Service A returned 500 Internal Server error with Service Unavailable error. Facing this error, few times intermittently

```
**Calling Service Logs:**

`DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: **500 Internal Server Error**: [<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>**Service Unavailable**</... (511 bytes)]]
2023-07-14 14:08:02.943 [http-nio-61010-exec-239] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 500 **INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR**`

**Called Microservice Status:**
Completed 200 OK

Rest template is used to call between Microservices

@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
  return builder.build();
}
```

Please help to resolve this issue

Expecting microservice calls to be return 200 status code if processed successfully

Comment: What do you see in your microservice's logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting Service Unavailable error and facing this error intermittently, then might be your Service B status is not UP continuously, due to some continuous deployment or so.

Please mention more details.

Answer (score -1):

There should have something wrong in the server side, and may be the client post some invalid headers or some invalid post body will cause server exceptions.